# Difficulties with checking if textfield is an ID from XML

Tags: xml, string, actionscript-3

I'm having a problem when I'm getting an ID from my XML and try to compare if a textfield is the same as that ID.

at first I'm using this code to get the ID and set it do my textfield named ID

```
 ID.text = imgData.Vehicle.Id[0];
```

The ID in this case is **44700008** and it's presented perfectly in my textfield.

then I am using this code to enter all the ID's from my XML to an XMLList

```
 var idList:XMLList = imgData.Vehicle.Id.children();
```

And this works great aswell. When I use ***trace(idList[0])*** the ID is **44700008**

but when I put in my if-statement wich goes like this:

```
   if(ID.text == idList[0])
{ //////Here is code to insert a picture from XML 
}
else
{
    trace("ID is not correct")
}
```

still when I run my code i only get the "ID is not correct" even though the ID on idList[0] is  **44700008** and my ID.text also is **44700008**

I think the problem is that it's converted to a string and string can't compare numbers. But how should I do to actually compare my ID.text and idList[0] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the answer.. I am declaring the ID.text = imgData.Vehicle.Id[0]; in the function above. Apparently the ID.text are empty by the time it goes into the next function.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the string conversion:

```
if (ID.text == idList[0].toString()) {
  // ...
```

You must ensure that your strings are properly trimmed.
You may have to call [`StringUtils#trim()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/StringUtil.html#trim%28%29) on them or:

```
s = s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gs, '');
```

Comment: I have enver seen the String#trim() function. Could you please direct me to a site where I can learn more about that? Because the .toString() didn't work. Thank you for very quick answer

Comment: @NiclasLundqvist My bad. It's `StringUtils#trim`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It still didn't work. I think I know why now. I have 2 different functions in my framescript. one is the one where ID.text = imgData.Vehicle.Id[0]; and the other is the If-statement. But it seems like outside the first function the ID.text is empty. If I try to trace(ID.text); outside the first function I'm getting nothing